# Laravel loop through all data in database through schedule command

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am looking for an efficient way to loop through all the records of all users, check for a condition and if the condition is met I need to send an email.

This task is to be done daily at some specified time. So a cron job will be running in the background.

Right now I am populating all the records for the database and using for loop to check the condition. This is working fine for now. But I don't think this is the best solution when data start growing.

Any idea on using limit to get whole database data?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic of the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of records, use chunk : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#chunking-results

```
DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: I think chunk is the method I am looking for. Thank you for pointing this. I missed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [laravel queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues) . You can check all the data and if the condition match dispatch and delay the send mail process to queue. [Tutorial 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFy-s7_SbYM)

Comment: I end up using chunk as the processing is done in a scheduled  time.